# Optimizing CSS with cssnano advanced transforms using Gulp + PostCSS

Tags: css, gulp, postcss, cssnano

My current working gulpfile.js:

```
    var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
    var gulp = require('gulp');
    var cssnano = require('cssnano');

    gulp.task('css', function () {
        var plugins = [
            cssnano()
        ];
        return gulp.src('css/*.css')
            .pipe(postcss(plugins))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('css/min/'));
    });
```

Gulp pipes all the CSS to PostCSS which runs them through cssnano, and they all land in *css/min*. Nice.

**How do I get cssnano to use advanced transforms?**

Ideally, with vars, or parameter objects instead of extarnal config scripts. 
I think the anwser might be on [this cssnano guide page](https://cssnano.co/guides/advanced-transforms), but I don't know how to make it work with Gulp+PostCSS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass options to the cssnano function, so I believe it is a matter of the following:

```
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var cssnano = require('cssnano');

gulp.task('css', function () {
    var plugins = [
        cssnano({
            preset: ['advanced', {
                // preset options here, e.g...
                discardComments: { removeAll: true }
            }]
        })
    ];
    return gulp.src('css/*.css')
        .pipe(postcss(plugins))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css/min/'));
});
```

Obviously ensure you've got `cssnano-preset-advanced` first via `npm install cssnano-preset-advanced --save-dev`